# How to change div properties D3 v4 angular 4 on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

Good day.
I have an angular 4 component that draws a D3 v4 graph. The graph is drawn fine but the problem comes when I try to trigger a change on a mouseover over. So for example when I mouse over a circle on the line graph I want a the rectangle to shrink(just for this example)Please any assistance will be appreciated below is an excerpt of the code that is not working:

```
g.selectAll("dot")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2)
      .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return x(d.time);
      })
      .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return y(d.value);
      })
      .on("mouseover",update)

    var div = this.svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .attr("width", "100px")
      .attr("height", "200px")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .enter().append("text").enter()
      .text("foo");
    function update()
    {
      div.setAttribute("width","10px");

    }
```

The above code draws a blue rectangle over the graph but on mosueover there is no change in size.

Comment: `div` is a D3 selection, not a HTML element. Thus, you should use the D3 method `attr()` instead. By the way, that `enter()` and `append("text")` at the end make no sense.

Comment: Hey gerardo no luck even with  div.attr("width","10px");

Comment: Did you remove those `enter()`? Try removing everything after `.style("opacity", 1)`, which is this: `.enter().append("text").enter().text("foo")`.

Comment: Yeah it is now    g.selectAll("dot")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2)
      .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return x(d.time);
      })
      .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return y(d.value);
      })
      .on("mouseover",update)

    var div = this.svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .attr("width", "100px")
      .attr("height", "200px")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .style("opacity", 1);
    function update()
    {
      div.attr("width","10px");

    }

Comment: I think it has with what ever changes happen inside update (cause i can see the changes if i inspect the changes inside the console if i output the div in update) arnt refelcted back to the graph.